# h2 on one line although container has fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is 520px wide with a H2 in it.  Normally the H2 breaks when it reaches the 520px boundary and goes to a new line.

On a current landing page I am working on this is not the case and I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is. Here is what I mean: http://snelgeldonlineverdienen.nl/landerstoutste/

I highlighted the div which is the container with a black border for more convenience.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.  Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain in specific terms what you're trying to accomplish and how your results differ from the desired results. Include any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enclosing div has a `white-space: nowrap;` style set.

Remove that, and the `H2` will span multiple lines.

Or, add:

```
white-space: normal;
```

to the `H2`

Comment: thanks! never in a million years i would have thought that this would be in a JS file. Great find!

Answer (score 1):

remove the property

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the H2